# JMeter - __Request Verification Token Failed for New user registration in MVC project

Tags: model-view-controller, jmeter, token

Request Verification Token is not identifying or getting assigned to a variable by JMeter for a new user registration

In GET, Request header - Request Verification Token is passed as Static one
In POST, Request header - Static request verification token is called and in **PAYLOAD** - **Another dynamic Request Verification Token is displaying.**

In POST url, I have used below Regular Expression Extractor:

**Field to check:** Request Headers
**Name of created variable**: Token
**Regular Expression:** input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="([A-Za-z0-9+=/-_]+?)"
**Template:** $1$
**Match no:** 0

**Queries:**

1. Do I need to use Regular Expression Extractor in GET URL also, If yes what regular expression need to be used?
2. How to pass Static request verification token value in GET & POST URL?
3. Do we need to use 2 Regular Expression Extractor in GET & POST URL?

Could you please provide solution?

Answer (score 0):

1. Field to check - needs to be **Response Body**
2. [Using regular expressions for extracting data from HTML is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), consider switching to [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter) instead.
3. We don't know the answers to your questions because we're not familiar with the application you're testing, if you have doubts with regards to which values need to be correlated - [record the same test scenario](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) 2 times and compare the generated test plans. All parameters which differ are a subject to correlation.